# list all items under a key of my bucket of AWS S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

In AWS S3, I have a bucket named `my-bucket`, with [AWS Ruby SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/), I can list all the items under `my-bucket` by ruby code:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2')

bucket = s3.bucket('my-bucket')

# Show only the first 50 items
bucket.objects.limit(50).each do |item|
  puts "Name:  #{item.key}"
  puts "URL:   #{item.presigned_url(:get)}"
end
```

This is fine. But under `my-bucket` I have the following file structure in S3:

```
my-bucket/
    customers/
         products/
              - data1.txt
              - data2.txt
              ...
```

My questions are:

**Q1.** With [AWS Ruby SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/), how can I list all the items under `my-bucket/customers/products/`?

**Q2.** How can I check e.g. `my-bucket/customers/products/data3.txt` exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Q1. With AWS Ruby SDK, how can I list all the items under
>   my-bucket/customers/products/?

`bucket.objects({prefix: "customers/products/"})`

> Q2. How can I check e.g. my-bucket/customers/products/data3.txt
>   exists?

Use the S3 Object [#exists?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#exists%3F-instance_method) method like:

`bucket.objects["customers/products/data3.txt"].exists?`

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to use wildcard for the `data3.txt` part? for example, I want to check does a file ending with `.txt` exist under `customers/products/`?

Comment: No, you would have to get the list of all the objects with that prefix and then scan through the returned list for any objects that have the ".txt" suffix.

Comment: Hmm... for the second line of code in your answer, I get this error ``method_missing': undefined method `[]' for #<Aws::Resources::Collection:0x007fa50440d228>` , then, I changed to `bucket.objects({prefix:"customers/products/data3.txt"}).exists?` but I get error `undefined method `exists?'`, any idea why?

Comment: It's defined right here in the SDK Docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#exists%3F-instance_method I'm not a Ruby programmer, I'm just pointing out the methods in the AWS SDK you need to use for the tasks you had a question about. I suggest you take the time to read the docs.

Comment: just change square brackets to curly brackets fix the issue :)